# changing type of a business entity

Tags: corporate-law

Is it possible to change a type of a business entity to a different one? For example private limited company into private company limited by shares.

EDIT: Please provide an answer without me specifying jurisdiction exactly. Let's think of the USA or the European Union.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Law.se. Which jurisdiction are you asking about? If you [edit] your question you can add tags like *england-and-wales, united-states* (together with a particular state) and the like.

Comment: Thank you for the welcoming. Initial post edited.

Comment: "...without me specifying jurisdiction exactly." This is simply too broad of a question.

Answer (score 0):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Most U.S. jurisdictions allow a change of entity type, although the mechanics differ.

In Colorado, the relevant statute for a change of entity type are Colorado Revised Statutes §§ [8-90-201 to 8-90-206](https://casetext.com/statute/colorado-revised-statutes/title-7-corporations-and-associations/corporations-and-associations/article-90-colorado-corporations-and-associations-act/part-2-merger-and-conversion-of-entities), which was colloquially called the "junction box statute" when it was adopted.

In the U.S., it is also possible for an entity that is organized as a limited liability company under state law [to elect to be taxed as if it were a corporation](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/small-business-self-employed-other-business/entities/entities-3), without actually changing its entity type for state law purposes.